why is remmina xrdp so slow
Remmina as a Chromebook/Linux app connected to xrdp via ssh to Ubuntu 22.04 paints the Ubuntu desktop nicely, but mouse and keyboard interactions are so slow as to be unusable (c. 12 seconds).
Can this be improved with configuration?

Are you using Remmina in ChromeOS and using ChromeOS to access Ubuntu remotely?

Can you try to access your Ubuntu from another computer, say, one running Ubuntu (remmina) or Windows (RDP)? We need to determine if the issue is with the Ubuntu computer or the ChromeOS computer.

Remmina (1.4.29) is running in the Crostini environment of the CB. I will try from another computer when I return home in 10 days I note that using Remmina's VNC plugin to access the same server works well. It's the RDP interface which is slow.

Then, if possible, just continue using VNC
